# Spring - Logging security violation at the end of all custom authentication providers

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

I have a business requirement where I'm using two custom authentication providers. Now, if the first provider can't successfully authenticate, it logs the violation entry in DB through ApplicationEventPublisher and the same goes for the second provider as well.

Now there are some users which can only be authenticated by the second provider and some by the first one, and for another business reason I need to use both the providers and allow both sets of users to authenticate themselves.

The issue here is I don't want the security violation to be logged if the user is able to authenticate itself through either of the providers.

Something like the violation logging only happens when both the providers have tried and failed. I thought of using AuthenticationFailureHandler for this.

**Expected Scenario**:

1. AuthProvider1 fails.
2. AuthProvider2 fails.
3. Only now, the violation gets logged(maybe through AuthenticationFailureHandler or something else that you folks might suggest).

Problem is how do I direct the execution flow to AuthenticationFailureHandler after both the Auth Providers are done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works currently - after looping through all of the available providers without successfully authenticating, the AuthenticationException from the last provider is thrown (or if all abstained and there's no exception a ProviderNotFoundException is thrown). This bounces flow back to the filter that called `ProviderManager.authenticate()` (typically a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`) and `AuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure()` is called to do whatever work is needed after an auth failure, typically redirecting back to the login page.

Check out the implementation of `ProviderManager` and `authenticate()` in particular, you'll see it's pretty close to what you're looking for. You might need to tweak the logic a bit, but should be able to reuse most of the rest.